# What kind of variable of this definition in python?

Tags: python

I met a problem when I read the book *machine learning in action*:
The file name is `treePlotter.py`,it contains a function to draw a tree from a dict with matplotlib. `createPlot` is the function called to draw, `plotTree` is a function called by `createPlot`, the code is as below:

```
def plotTree(myTree, parentPt, nodeTxt):#if the first key tells you what feat was split on
    numLeafs = getNumLeafs(myTree)  #this determines the x width of this tree
    depth = getTreeDepth(myTree)
    firstStr = myTree.keys()[0]     #the text label for this node should be this
    print plotTree.xOff;
    cntrPt = (plotTree.xOff + (1.0 + float(numLeafs))/2.0/plotTree.totalW, plotTree.yOff)
    print plotTree.xOff
    plotMidText(cntrPt, parentPt, nodeTxt)
    plotNode(firstStr, cntrPt, parentPt, decisionNode)
    secondDict = myTree[firstStr]
    plotTree.yOff = plotTree.yOff - 1.0/plotTree.totalD
    for key in secondDict.keys():
        if type(secondDict[key]).__name__=='dict':#test to see if the nodes are dictonaires, if not they are leaf nodes   
            plotTree(secondDict[key],cntrPt,str(key))        #recursion
        else:   #it's a leaf node print the leaf node
            plotTree.xOff = plotTree.xOff + 1.0/plotTree.totalW
            plotNode(secondDict[key], (plotTree.xOff, plotTree.yOff), cntrPt, leafNode)
            plotMidText((plotTree.xOff, plotTree.yOff), cntrPt, str(key))
    plotTree.yOff = plotTree.yOff + 1.0/plotTree.totalD
#if you do get a dictonary you know it's a tree, and the first element will be another dict

def createPlot(inTree):
    fig = plt.figure(1, facecolor='white')
    fig.clf()
    axprops = dict(xticks=[], yticks=[])
    createPlot.ax1 = plt.subplot(111, frameon=False, **axprops)    #no ticks
    #createPlot.ax1 = plt.subplot(111, frameon=False) #ticks for demo puropses 
    plotTree.totalW = float(getNumLeafs(inTree))
    plotTree.totalD = float(getTreeDepth(inTree))
    plotTree.xOff = -0.5/plotTree.totalW; plotTree.yOff = 1.0;
    plotTree(inTree, (0.5,1.0), '')
    plt.show()
```

Which I can't imagine is that: as a funciont, plotTree has the . method to create a new variable in the itself! I ever studied C/C++ and Java, only Classes have . handle.
Is function of python also a kind of class? If so, even can we create public variable of it outside the class?

Comment: No, everything's an object. Only classes are classes.

Comment: @leeladam, I added something in the last of the question. If it is a class, in the function, we create new variables of the object outside without method in the object. Is it?

Comment: @ChaosCosmos: yes, new attributes (on most mutable objects) can be created with `object.attribute = some_value`. Getters and setters are not necessary, and are usually considered very bad style in Python code.

Comment: @Wooble,thx. The above code is from the book, maybe the author's programming habit is not so good.

Comment: It's not; that's some awful code there. :) As a Java developer moving to Python, you may see lots of Python code where you think "they should have written a class" and be wrong, but in this case, you'd be absolutely right. Encapsulating state within a function object is just weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's functions are indeed objects (instances of the `function` class). Modules and classes are actually objects too. Well, everything you can name is an object.

Now using function attributes this way is very very bad practice...